# En un archivo html me da un error a la hora de probarlo

Tags: javascript, html

Como mencione antes, a la hora de ejecutar el archivo HTML en una pagina no me general la tabla, el objetivo es obtener una lista de numeros aleatorios pero no logro obtenerla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Trabajo Quiz </title>
<script>
function ObtenerArregloAleatorio()
{
    var  filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
    var  columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);
    var numero = parseDouble(document.getElementById("numero").value);
    numero = filas * columnas;
    var aleatorio = parseInt(document.getElementById("aleatorio").value);
    document.write( " <table border='2'>  ");

    for(i=1;i<=filas;i++)
    {
        aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
        if(aleatorio < 100)
        {
            aleatorio = aleatorio * 10;
        }
        document.write( " <tr>  ");
        for(j=1; j<=columnas; j++)<
        {
                document.write( "<td>"+ aleatorio + "</td>");
        }
        document.write( " </tr>  ");
    }
    document.write( " </table>  ");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="filas"><br>
<input type="text" id="columnas"><br>
<button  type="button" onClick="ObtenerArregloAleatorio()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es todo el codigo.
/no leer lo siguiente(es para que me deje montar la edición que me dice que mayormente tengo todo codigo)

Comment: y cual es el error que te da?

Comment: SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'aleatorio' is not defined
tryit.asp (36,33)

 SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'startAuction'

Comment: lo cambie a ObtenerArregloAleatorio pero me sale el siguiente error SCRIPT5009: 'ObtenerArregloAleatorio' is not defined

Comment: Cambiar el nombre de la funcion no era una solucion, es nomas para que sea mas claro... Deberias incluir tu codigo HTML para que podamos ver como estas incluyendo este script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui esta el codigo que brindaste funcionalm tenias algunos errores de sintaxis y elementos que no existian; ademas, el hecho de estar llamando el script antes de que la pagina cargara por completo puede tambien causar algunos problemas.

Los `document.getElementById("numero").value` y `document.getElementById("aleatorio").value` regresan un valor `undefined` porque no existen elementos con ese `id` en tu HTML; a parte de un simbolo `>` presente antes de la llave de apertura del segundo `for`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Trabajo Quiz </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="filas" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="columnas" /><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="ObtenerArregloAleatorio()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
  <script>
    function ObtenerArregloAleatorio() {
      var filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
      var columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);
      // var numero = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero").value);
      var numero = filas * columnas;
      // var aleatorio = parseInt(document.getElementById("aleatorio").value);
      document.write(" <table border='2'>  ");

      for (i = 1; i <= filas; i++) {
        var aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
        if (aleatorio < 100) {
          aleatorio = aleatorio * 10;
        }
        document.write(" <tr>  ");
        for (j = 1; j <= columnas; j++) {
          document.write("<td>" + aleatorio + "</td>");
        }
        document.write(" </tr>  ");
      }
      document.write(" </table>  ");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes errores en el código.

- Tienes un `<` después del segundo for (pone `for(j=1; j<=columnas; j++)<`).
- `parseDouble` no existe, usa `parseFloat`.
- No tienes ningún elemento con id `numero`, así que `document.getElementById("numero").value` da error.
- No tienes ningún elemento con id `aleatorio`, así que `document.getElementById("aleatorio").value` da error.

Arréglalo y lo tendrás.

Ten en cuenta que `document.write()` sobreescribe tu página, así que aparecerá la tabla pero desaparecerá todo lo demás.

También ten en cuenta que estás generando un número aleatorio por fila de la tabla. Tal vez lo que quieres es un número por celda, pero no lo sé.

Para generar uno por celda tienes que poner el código que calcula el número aleatorio dentro del segundo `for`. Abajo tienes un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Trabajo Quiz </title>
<script>
function generarTablaAleatorios() {
    var totalFilas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
    var totalColumnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);

    document.write("<table border='2'>");
    for (var indiceFila = 1; indiceFila <= totalFilas ; indiceFila++) {
        document.write("<tr>");

        for(var indiceColumna = 1; indiceColumna <= totalColumnas; indiceColumna++) {
            document.write( "<td>" + generarAleatorio() + "</td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}

function generarAleatorio() {
    aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    if(aleatorio < 100) {
        aleatorio = aleatorio * 10;
    }
    return aleatorio;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="filas"><br>
    <input type="text" id="columnas"><br>
    <button  type="button" onClick="generarTablaAleatorios()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: como lo hago para cada celda?

Comment: @PROLEPRO para eso tienes que poner el código que genera aleatorios dentro del bucle interior, el de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen los compañeros hay errores de sintaxis (bastantes).
Parte del código no tiene sentido (aquel en que declaras una variable, se le asigna un valor y a continuación se le asignas otro sin haberla usado).
Luego con `document.write` se sobreescribe el contenido del documento HTML.
Y finalmente el código JS debe ir al final, para que en cualquier caso el elemento del que se va a extraer un valor ya exista (esto no ocurriría si pones el código al principio y llamas a la función principal directamente antes de que se cargue toda la página.

Te pongo un ejemplo funcional, puedes cambiar los valores por defecto para la tabla.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Numeros aleatorios</h1>

    <label>Núm. de filas:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="filas" value="2"><br>
    <br>

    <label>Núm. de cols:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="columnas" value="2"><br>
    <br>

    <label>Núm. de celdas resultantes:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="cells" readonly><br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="run()">Generar tabla</button>



    <br>
    <div id="result" style="padding: 5%"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function $(id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        function run()
        {
            var filas    = parseInt($("filas").value);
            var columnas = parseInt($("columnas").value);
            var numero   = filas * columnas;
            $("cells").value = numero

            console.log(filas + "/" + columnas + " -> " + numero); // trace

            var html = "";
            for(var i=1; i<=filas; i++)
            {
                var random_number = getRandomNumber();
                html = html + "<tr>\n";
                for(var j=1; j<=columnas; j++)
                {
                    html = html + "<td>" + random_number + "</td>";
                }
                html += "</tr>\n";
            }


            var table       = document.createElement("table");
            table.border    = 2;
            table.innerHTML = html;

            $("result").appendChild(table);
        }

        function getRandomNumber()
        {
            var result = Math.random() * 1000;
            if(result < 100)
            {
                result = result * 10;
            }

            return Math.floor(result);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```